# EOF error while pulling images from docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, dockerhub, docker-proxy

I am getting following error for

docker pull openjdk

```
Using default tag: latest

Pulling repository docker.io/library/openjdk

Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/openjdk/images: EOF
```

I have set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf and /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf respectively.

Still I am not able to pull any images from docker hub.

Following is the docker version output
Client:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 10 20:20:01 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 10 20:20:01 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Comment: Do you have your username/password set in the proxy string?

Comment: Yes! https://<username>:<password>@<ip>:<port>

Comment: Does your password include any special character that would need to be percent-encoded? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data)

Comment: yes password contains a $ percent-encoded with %24

Comment: in http_proxy what should be the value of IP? Is it VM IP or something else. As my username and password is correct only suspect is around IP

Comment: You can use the IP (to avoid any DNS name resolution issue). Make sure your proxy URL start with http:// though. Never https. Even for the https_proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my setting:

```
etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
more http-proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.mycompany.com:8080/" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.mycompany.com:8080/"  "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,.mycompany.com"
```

Note that `HTTP_PROXY` like `HTTPS_PROXY` both are using an *http* URL for the proxy. And make sure (with `NO_PROXY`) that any internal URL does *not* use the proxy.